# assignment from incompatible type in array of pointer (c)

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

i'm using an array of pointer (which are addresses of functions).
I'm parsing multiple types of data (`char *`, `int`, etc) to them.
To avoid any type error i'm using multiples `void *`.
That's why i'm confused because the compiler says that they are incompatible type (thus, it work when I compile it).

The array prototype is : `void    *(*arg_handler[4])(void *arg);`

I'm using a function called list to save the different addresses and return the function address with the specific arguments:

```
void    *list(int x, void *arg)
{
  arg_handler[0] = &my_putstr;
  arg_handler[1] = &my_put_printable;
  arg_handler[2] = &my_put_nbr;
  arg_handler[3] = &my_put_nbr;
  return (arg_handler[x](arg));
}
```

I'm calling list from the main function through:

```
list(f_type(s[x + 1]), va_arg(args, void *));
```

but I can't figure out why I got this error:

```
 warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

for :

```
arg_handler[0] = &my_putstr;
arg_handler[1] = &my_put_printable;
arg_handler[2] = &my_put_nbr;
arg_handler[3] = &my_put_nbr;
```

any Idea ?

Comment: Its the the complete warning? I'd expected it to be more specific.

Comment: Also you get this warning for exactly which line of code?

Comment: yes this is the complete warning

Comment: It's specified in the "for" section (just before "any idea")

Comment: What is `f_type`, please?

Comment: I would go away and bang your head on a hard surface. Then make a different design for the code.

Comment: So then how is `my_put_nbr` defined?

Comment: `f_type` is an int which correspond to a number between 0 and 3; it permit to call the specific function in `arg_handler`

Comment: `int     my_put_nbr(signed long long int nb);`

Comment: So why do you think you could assign this function `my_put_nbr` to a function pointer (`arg_handler[3]`) of completely different type, though and wonder the compiler complains?

Comment: thus I made an other function (f_type) to send only the type that the fnction require (int to my_put_nbr for example).

Comment: even if I set my_put_nbr to a void * it wont work. The types are handled by f_type which permit to send the data to a specific function which handle this type of data : int to my_put_nbr for example

Comment: `arg_handler[3]` expects something like `void * foo(void*)`, but you assign `int my_put_nbr(signed long long int nb);`.

Comment: Yes but the concept of the `void *` is that it is replaced by the type of data sent to it

Comment: No, that's not the concept of `void*`, `void*` stays `void*` just like any other variable's type in C.

Comment: But why does it compile and work though ?

Comment: An incompatible type should "generally" result in a segfault

Comment: "*But why does it compile ...*" Because C compilers try to do their best ...assuming the programmer knows what s/he is doing.

Comment: So if i want to use arrays of pointers I would do one for each type ?

Comment: "segfaults" happen at run.time. You are still struggling with compile time. Just pass `-Werror` to GCC to be  more strict.

Comment: C is a "typed" language, yes.

Comment: "*... and work though*" Do not rely on it, its provoking undefined behaviour and/or relying on some compiler extensions.

Answer (score -1):

As alk said the warnings were appearing because the 4 functions where not typed as `void *`. So instead of making an array for each type I converted the functions as `void *` as so :

```
arg_handler[0] = (void *)my_putstr;
arg_handler[1] = (void *)my_put_printable;
arg_handler[2] = (void *)my_put_nbr;
arg_handler[3] = (void *)my_put_nbr;
```

Comment: Using the casting hammer mostly always nearly ever just silences the compiler, its mostly never ever at no times prevents to code from running into undefined behaviour ...

Comment: f_type controls the parsing of the data.

Comment: So the data will always fit to the type of the function I call in arg handler